# Randomly splitting records in Vertica into Test and Control

Tags: sql, random, vertica

I am working on a use case to partition records by date and randomly assign 80% of the records into Test and 20% into Control in Vertica. How can this be done using SQL.

```
**For example, Data may look like this:**
UserA 01/01/2000
UserB 01/01/2000 
UserC 01/01/2000 
UserD 01/01/2000 
UserE 01/01/2000
...  
UserF 02/02/2001
UserG 02/02/2001 
UserH 02/02/2001 
UserI 02/02/2001 
UserJ 02/02/2001

**Output should look like:**
UserA 01/01/2000 Test
UserB 01/01/2000 Control
UserC 01/01/2000 Test
UserD 01/01/2000 Test
UserE 01/01/2000 Control
...
UserF 02/02/2001 Control
UserG 02/02/2001 Test
UserH 02/02/2001 Test
UserI 02/02/2001 Test
UserJ 02/02/2001 Control
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using the [PERCENT_RANK Analytic Function](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/PERCENT_RANKAnalytic.htm?zoom_highlight=percent) and ordering the records in each partition by the [RANDOM function](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Mathematical/RANDOM.htm?tocpath=SQL%20Reference%20Manual%7CSQL%20Functions%7CMathematical%20Functions%7C_____24):

```
with t as (
             select 'UserA' as u, date '2000-01-01' as d
   union all select 'UserB' as u, date '2000-01-01' as d
   union all select 'UserC' as u, date '2000-01-01' as d
   union all select 'UserD' as u, date '2000-01-01' as d
   union all select 'UserE' as u, date '2000-01-01' as d
   --
   union all select 'UserF' as u, date '2001-02-02' as d
   union all select 'UserG' as u, date '2001-02-02' as d
   union all select 'UserH' as u, date '2001-02-02' as d
   union all select 'UserI' as u, date '2001-02-02' as d
   union all select 'UserJ' as u, date '2001-02-02' as d
)
select u,
       d, 
       percent_rank() over (partition by d order by random()) as pctrank,
       case when percent_rank() over (partition by d order by random()) <= 0.8 then 'Test' else 'Control' end bucket
  from t
 order by d, u;
```

Output:

```
u      d           pctrank  bucket   
-----  ----------  -------  -------  
UserA  2000-01-01  0,25     Test     
UserB  2000-01-01  0,75     Test     
UserC  2000-01-01  0,5      Test     
UserD  2000-01-01  0        Test     
UserE  2000-01-01  1        Control  
UserF  2001-02-02  0,25     Test     
UserG  2001-02-02  0        Test     
UserH  2001-02-02  0,75     Test     
UserI  2001-02-02  1        Control  
UserJ  2001-02-02  0,5      Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than that. Vertica has Machine Learning functions and clauses:
We usually split the data directly into new tables:

```
CREATE TABLE indata_control AS
SELECT * FROM indata
TABLESAMPLE 20;

-- assuming that `username` is the primary key ...
CREATE TABLE indata_test AS
SELECT * FROM indata
WHERE username NOT IN (
  SELECT username FROM indata_control;
);
```

If, however, you prefer to have a categorising column , then go as below.
Be aware, however, that updating all rows in a table is deleting all rows from the table and adding all rows again - as Vertica never really deletes a row - which makes this method much less efficient.....

```
ALTER TABLE indata ADD bucket VARCHAR(7);
UPDATE indata SET bucket='Control' WHERE RANDOM() <= 0.2;
UPDATE indata SET bucket='Test' WHERE bucket IS NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Or, come to think of it - better than UPDATE-ing all rows in the table - which is a bad idea no matter what the DBMS - go:

```
ALTER TABLE indata RENAME TO indata_old;
CREATE TABLE indata LIKE indata_old INCLUDING PROJECTIONS;
ALTER TABLE indata ADD bucket VARCHAR(7);
INSERT INTO indata 
  SELECT 
    *
  , CASE WHEN RANDOM() < 0.2 
      THEN 'Test'
      ELSE 'Control'
    END AS bucket
FROM indata_old;
COMMIT;
DROP TABLE indata_old;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large amount of data, then a simple `case` might be sufficient:

```
(case when random() < 0.8 then 'test' else 'control' end)
```

Comment: Thought of that one, too - but I dread the Vertica delete vectors - and with that, you add one delete vector per row ....

Comment: @marcothesane . . . I'm missing something, because this is intended for a `select` statement, not a `delete` a delete statement.

Comment: I understood they wanted to add a column with `Test` or `Control` as content to the existing table. That works hardly without an UPDATE ... if you want to use RANDOM()  on 20% of the rows ...

Comment: @marcothesane . . . I do not interpret the question as updating the original table, just creating a new version that has the additional column.

Comment: Then, yours is more elegant - a CASE WHEN is more efficient than two updates ...